# Как сделать чтобы текст в Tkinter копировался

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, label

Как сделать так, чтобы текст внутри окна *tkinter* копировался? 
Сейчас же он просто не выделяется. \

Создавал вот так:

```
    cs = random.randint(8,30)
    symbols = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_'
    rand = (''.join(choice(symbols) for i in range(cs)))
    l2 = Label(gu, text=f"{rand}",
        font="Arial 8")
    l2.config(bd=50)
    l2.pack()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: я хочу чтоб текст в окне tkinter выделялся, и его можно было бы скопировать с помощью ctrl + c, ctrl + v

Comment: Чтобы выделялся - используйте Entry или Text вместо Label.

Comment: Entry вроди как на ввод

Comment: Без разницы, можно и текст в нем показывать программно.

Comment: В таком случае этот текст можно будет изменить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете выделить отдельные слова в виджете `Label`.
Если вам нужна такая возможность, вам нужно будет использовать виджет `Text`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


root = tk.Tk()

cs = random.randint(8, 30)
symbols = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_'
rand = (''.join(random.choice(symbols) for i in range(cs)))

text = tk.Text(root, height=1, font="Arial 8")
text.tag_configure("bold", font="Arial 8 bold")
text.insert("end", rand, "bold") 
text.configure(state="disabled")
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну тут все-таки логичнее было бы использовать Entry, а не Text